# How to implement the Linux top command UI using JAVA?

Tags: java, linux, top-command

How to implement the Linux 'top command' style UI using JAVA?

And How to run jar in server side itself, and i can see the state of the program after i log in SSH.

Comment: I mean the program can refresh the shell it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give [this](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html) a try. I'm assuming that you're looking for an ASCII terminal UI toolkit... which I'd recommend, because terminal codes are rather painful to write by hand.

Answer (score 2):

For your second question:

java -jar jarfile.jar

Will run a jar file that is written to be run at the command line.  Anything this program prints to standard out will be displayed for you to see.

This entry talks a bit about building a jar file that can be run in this way:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29

Comment: If you setup a shell script to issue this command (if using OpenSSH), you can create a new user account and use the script as the "shell" for the account. It'll allow you to SSH directly into your app without allowing the user to drop to command-line.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a Java Curses Framework like this:
http://javacurses.sourceforge.net or CHARVA